# Movie identification: a girl who grows up very fast

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think I watched this movie back in the late 90s, all I remember is a couple finds a baby girl in the woods and take her to their cabin. The next day the man comes home only to find the baby has grown up to a young girl. I guess the girl had blue blood.

I also remember the name "Kaya", but I don't remember whose name it is.

Comment: Blue-blooded girl; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53027/movie-identification-girl-taken-to-a-hospital-they-discover-her-blood-is-blue

Comment: Take a look at this [post on meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for a list of details you can add in order to make it easier to identify this film.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My first thought was *[The Tale of Princess Kaguya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Princess_Kaguya)*, which has a girl found in a forest by a couple, and given a similar name to what you remember. However, the release date for that was 2013 and that was a cartoon.

However, there was an earlier live-action film, *[Princess from the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_from_the_Moon)* with the same plotline, based on ["The Tale of the Bamboo Cutter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Bamboo_Cutter), where the character is even named Kaya. Summary from Wikipedia:

> One day wood cutter Taketori-no-Miyatsuko (Toshiro Mifune) discovers a baby girl while he's out in the forest visiting his daughter's grave. Not wanting to leave the infant to die and because of her resemblance to his dead daughter, he takes the child home with him- only to discover that the child grows at an extraordinarily fast rate. Incredibly beautiful, the now grown child Kaya (Yasuko Sawaguchi) attracts the attention of everyone around her, including the land's Emperor. Unwilling to accept their advances, Kaya gives the men a list of increasingly difficult tasks. By the film's end Kaya returns to outer-space by way of a space ship.

[image: Movie Poster]

Comment: I think you have a good answer, and thank you for trying to improve it. I modified it a little with a quote from the summary on Wikipedia, and an explanation of your reasoning. Please, edit away anything that you feel does not fit what you wanted to say. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks FuzzyBoots for tidying up my post. I'll try to follow that sort of template in the future.

Comment: ^_^ It's not a rigid template, but I generally phrase my identification answers by linking to the name, providing a quoted summary from that source, addressing any specific points, possibly with more links or quotes, and then adding a picture of the movie poster or media cover if available. Optionally, if you paste a Youtube link on its own line, it will embed the video. Sometimes, I'll post a trailer or an excerpt from a movie to make it even easier to recognize.