# '80s movie with gold female alien

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a few minutes of this alien sci-fi movie as a little kid in the '80s while sneaking into my parents room. All I remember is this bright glowing gold/yellow female alien. This movie haunted me as a child, and I would love to see this movie as an adult if anyone has any idea what it is.

The movie was in color. I believe it was American. It wasn’t an animation, and I believe it was on another planet. The female was not wearing clothes as far as I can remember. I’m pretty sure it was a VHS movie. And yes I saw the movie in the 80s but the graphics for the alien seemed pretty advanced so I imagine it was made in that decade.

Comment: Do you have more specifics you can recall (was it American/English, was it animated, did it take place on Earth or somewhere else?)

Comment: Was this movie in English or another language? Also do you recall if it was being shown on TV (eg a tv movie or episode) or a rental/vhs (eg a feature film)?

Comment: To clarify, the timeframe "80ies" is when you saw the movie, not when it was produced? The description also somewhat fits [Metropolis (1927)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0017136/), after all.

Comment: I believe it was American. It wasn’t an animation, and I believe it was on another planet. The female was not wearing clothes as far as I can remember. I’m pretty sure it was a VHS movie. And yes I saw the movie in the 80s but the graphics for the alien seemed pretty advanced so I imagine it was made in that decade

Comment: Also the movie was in color, but the movie Metropolis looks cool, and I’ll have to watch it now!

Comment: I know the movie you are asking about but can’t remember the name. I remember another scene where she is rolling up panty hose on her legs and puts on lipstick before she gets out of a car I think.

Comment: A distant home? A scene at 1 hour 28 minute mark: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrh6V0LjmQk Potentially a duplicate of this one: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53027/movie-where-a-girl-taken-to-a-hospital-they-discover-her-blood-is-blue-neighbo

Comment: Could you have seen a snippet from the *Species* franchise and embellished the memory in your nightmares?

Answer (score 20):

There's not much to go on, but this sounds like it could be *[Cocoon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088933/)* (1985), which had a number of golden glowing aliens, including Steve Guttenberg's love interest.  A number of characteristic scenes can be seen in this montage.

Comment: I loved cocoon growing up, and honestly that is a great answer. The alien was similar to the glowing creatures in cocoon except there was only one, a female, from what i can remember and she was more frightening than the ones in cocoon

Answer (score 13):

The Doctor Who story [The Claws of Axos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Claws_of_Axos) had golden aliens, both male and female. Does this clip look at all familiar?

Comment: Thank you for your help, Sorry to make it confusing, but she was more fiery/glowing than actual gold

Answer (score 4):

Could it be Dot Matrix in Space Balls?

I am not entirely sure how old you were in the 80's, or even which part of the 80's you are referencing, but if it is late 80's and you were smaller, maybe Dot Matrix was what you were seeing?  I could definitely imagine her "haunting" someone.

[image: golden robot, with the impression of a dress built into its shape. The robot has a human wig, and is holding a white parasol. There is a desert dune filling the background.]

For those who may not know, this is from Spaceballs (1987)

Comment: I made a big edit to put the main point of your answer at the top, please roll it back if you want, but can you keep the image description?

Comment: ...and was voiced by Joan Rivers... that's enough to scare anyone, child or adult... ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I like this, but she was a special effects alien that was similar in facial features at least to human and she was glowing rather than actually made of gold

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it was Martian Chronicles?

Comment: The linked video doesn't work for me (says it has been blocked on copyright grounds). Can you provide more detail in your answer?

Comment: Sorry that happened!

Comment: On Youtube, try searching "Martian Chronicles First expedition", posted by gunner9365 . I hope it's what you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. From what I recall the alien did not wear clothing

Answer (score -5):

https://images.app.goo.gl/K5chP3Ddi4uZhDfx8
Species (1995)
I think it might be this movie

Comment: Images on image hosting services don't work very well here. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114508/ has additional footage and information. But the 1995 date makes it seem unlikely.

Comment: @tripleee it's not on any hosting service, it's just sharing Google Image Search result.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/209033)